# rails: how to log which i18n translation keys are still used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, internationalization

How can I log the usage of translation keys to find out which are deprecated? My idea is to log every key access into the db by overloading the t helper method. After letting the app run for a month or two I would check which keys are used and delete the rest. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `alias_method_chain` to intercept the call to `t` and do your logging:

```
module ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper    
  def t_with_logging(key, options={})
    Rails.logger.info "TEST"
    t_without_logging(key, options)
  end
  alias_method_chain :t, :logging
end
```

Then you can use `<%= t ... %>` in your views and it'll do your logging.